# Nuget is not installed. CMake Error at .../CMakeLists.txt:29 Integrity check for .../windows/nuget.exe failed

Tags: flutter

I get this error when I want to run my project in windows mode.

```
Nuget is not installed.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/webview_windows/windows/CMakeLists.txt:29 (message):
  Integrity check for F:/flutter_projects/my_project_name/build/windows/nuget.exe
  failed.


Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

But nuget had been installed before. I can run my other flutter project in windows with no errors. path to nuget.exe exists in environment variables.
How can I solve this?

Comment: it might be happening for a specific project. try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app/restart the ide/pc. This happens to me on test project where I used hundreds of packages[& create new project]

Comment: after `flutter clean`  says: 'Nuget is not installed.
Attempting to download nuget.' how can I convince it that there is already  nuget installed?

Comment: I might've solved it by installing manually. [try this](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/819)

Comment: after `flutter clean`, it showed: `Nuget is not installed. Attempting to download nuget.` I waited few minutes, then project run. Thanks for your help:)